# Non-persistent installation on hdd

Tags: grub2, persistence

I'm looking for a way to make an Ubuntu installation non-persistent, but I don't want it to completly reset itself after reboot. Instead I want it to go back to a specific point where  all required software is installed and the workstation is properly configured to comply with corporate requirements. Also, I want no grub menu, I want it to boot directly into this non-persistent image. Any guides or tips about achieving this? Is it even possible?

Comment: The concept of  "freezing" a system after customization is handled by the `overlayroot` package. Googling will lead you to documentation and usage. Some kind of bootloader is required for ANY operating system -- you can choose GRUB or something else, but there must be one.

Comment: What makes a Ubuntu install persistent is a file or partition named "writable" (or casper-rw). Once you get the drive how you want it, make a copy of writable. and use it to overwrite the HDD when you wish. Mkusb is a good starting point. Mkusb also comes with a feature that allows you to backup home and replace it at will.

Answer (score 0):

as @user535733 stated, overlayroot was the package I was looking for, so for anyone who needs guidance you can install it (ubuntu minimal installation does not install it by default) by entering

> sudo apt install overlayroot

in your terminal, and then

> sudo nano /etc/overlayroot.conf.

Then at the end of the page you have to change te value of **overlayroot** to **"tmpfs"**.

This will make the system behave like a normal live usb, but there are a lot of other posible configurations, so make sure you read the corresponding documentation.